# jQuery onclick on other element

Tags: jquery

I have a link for menu profile. It has a class called 'user-button'. When user clicks on it, jquery adds another class to ul list to display it.

```
$(".user-button").click(function() {
    if(!$(".arrow").hasClass('toggle')) {
        $(".arrow").addClass('toggle');
        $(".profile-action").addClass('display-it');
    } else {
        $(".arrow").removeClass('toggle');
        $(".profile-action").removeClass('display-it');
    }
});
```

Image reference: http://cl.ly/0R1u3A0h341s2w3a3Y3L

How do i make user click on other element such as body to close '.profile-action'?
eg: facebook modaless

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
$('html').click(function() {
     $(".arrow").removeClass('toggle');
     $(".profile-action").removeClass('display-it');
 });
```

And change your current code to prevent propgation:

```
$(".user-button").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(!$(".arrow").hasClass('toggle')) {
        $(".arrow").addClass('toggle');
        $(".profile-action").addClass('display-it');
    } else {
        $(".arrow").removeClass('toggle');
        $(".profile-action").removeClass('display-it');
    }
});
```